# Three value checkbox Razor MVC C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a model that I bind to the view which works great for all the members in my model, except for the bool? members.

My view is basically a search-filter popup window where users can either choose to filter our records by:

- Has phone (they will set checkbox to true)
- Doesn't have phone (they will leave the checkbox unchecked)
- It doesn't matter if they do or they dont (that's why I need a third option for that)

Technically my model's bool member will have either `true`, `false` or `null`

In my code, if the user doesn't set the checkbox, it is set by default to `false`, if they do tick the checkbox then it is set to `true`

How can I approach this problem?

`@Html.LabelFor(m => m.hasphone, "Has Phone ", new { @class = "control-label" })
@Html.CheckBoxFor(m => hasphone, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", value = Model.id, @checked = false } })`

Comment: You can use radio buttons or create your own helper as can see [here](https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/mvc/htmlhelper-radiobutton-radiobuttonfor)

Comment: you need to make your property nullable. like `public bool? HasPhone {get;set;}` and then set the value to `null`

Answer (score 1):

It's because a checkbox or radioButton for that matter have only two state, checked or unchecked.

in your description it seems like doesn't have phone or doesn't matter leave the box unchecked anyway so why do you need a third choice ?

If you really want 3 choice use a set of three radio buttons, one for each choice, or a dropdownlist.

Comment: Say we have 100 records 50 with phone and 50 without phone, if he ticked "Yes with phones" then he gets 50, If he ticked "No without only please" then he gets 50. If he wants any then he gets 100

Comment: There are 3 options, so use a radio button.

Comment: I would use @Html.EditorFor(m=> m.HasPhone, new { @class = "form-check-input", Value = m.HasPhone})

Comment: Yes radio button seems like it is what's needed, don't know why I didnt see that before

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured out how to do it in Razor, in case anyone gets stuck

```
@Html.LabelFor(m => m.hasphone, "Has Phone ", new { @class = "control-label" })
<fieldset id="hasphone">
     <label><input type="radio" name="hasphone" class="form-control" value="true" />Yes</label>
     <label><input type="radio" name="hasphone" class="form-control" value="false" />No</label>
     <label><input type="radio" name="hasphone" class="form-control" />Any</label>
</fieldset>
```

The idea is to create a group that holds the 3 options, name your group the same name as the property's name `<fieldset id="hasphone">`

Then set the radiobutton name to the group name `name="hasphone"`, and finally the first radio button will have a value of true `value="true"` that corresponds to the model's member `true` value, false corresponds to `false`

And finally by not setting the value of the 3rd radio button, you get the null value